# ExtJS 4.2 get the store of child component

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a `panel` that **dynamically** I can add as items a Grid, Chart, etc.

Any of those "`Widgets`" (grid, chart, etc.) have a `store`.

> My `panel` has a "`refresh tool`" that `onRefreshClick` I want to reload the "**Widget**" `store`.

In my main Controller I have:

```
onRefreshClick: function (tool) {
        console.log('refresh widget store');

        var me = this,
            panel = tool.up('panel');

        // here I want to access the store of the child item.

        // So I can do:
        /*

            widgetStore.load();

        */

    },
```

I won't know if it's widget is a grid, chart, dataview, etc? So I just have to get the store of the child component.

> Any clue on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your grid, chart, etc. is a child component of `panel = tool.up('panel');` ?

Comment: Grid, chart, etc are an item of panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use ComponentQuery to retrieve a store, so I'd do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < panel.items.items.length; i++) {
    try {
        store = panel.items.items[i].getStore();
        if (store != null) break;
    } catch (err) {
        //the component you looped through does not have a store...
    }
}

if (store != null)
    store.load();
```

Not beautiful, but it should work. Now, if sometimes your component are nested maybe you could refactor this into a recursive function (a function that calls itself)

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.each(panel.query(), function(widget){
   if(!Ext.isEmpty(widget.getStore()) widget.getStore().load();
})
```